# How to tag a word?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I need to categorize typos in text and tag words as per the image. For example, instead of "LIB" would be "TYP" (to indicate a typo), and instead of "skins" would be the word, such as "recieve" (purposely misspelled in this case to indicate a typo). I have no idea how to reproduce the image effect (above the arrow). Any idea how to do it?[image: Example]

Comment: sorry I have edited my answer plese see it

Comment: How did you define the colors so precisely? green!75!blue!50!white, for example.

Comment: googling skills)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You want to have this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mylib}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=0.4pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  right=0mm,left=4mm,arc=1pt,boxsep=2pt,before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
  colframe=green!50!black,coltext=green!25!black,colback=green!10!white,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[green!75!blue!50!white] (frame.south west)
    rectangle node[text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries\tiny,rotate=90] {TYP} ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}}


\begin{document}

\mylib{recieve}

\end{document}
```

Also if You wnt to change font to enother just add option something like that `fontupper=\ttfamily`

Comment: I think that being `TYP` also a parameter (with a default value) would make `\mylib`  command more flexible.